# Breaking up assertions - or not

Tags: assert, assertions

Is there a consensus about which of the following alternatives to go with (here exemplified in the C language)?

1. One assertion for all parameters:

   ```
   int f(int m, int n)
   {
      assert((m >= 0) && (m <= mmax) && (n >= 0) && (n <= nmax));
      ...
   }
   ```
2. One assertion per parameter:

   ```
   int f(int m, int n)
   {
       assert((m >= 0) && (m <= mmax));
       assert((n >= 0) && (n <= nmax));
       ...
   }
   ```
3. Assertions with atomic conditions:

   ```
   int f(int m, int n)
   {
       assert(m >= 0);
       assert(m <= mmax);
       assert(n >= 0);
       assert(n <= nmax);
       ...
   }
   ```

Comment: In this example I personally find the third option to be more readable (and more capable of identifying the specific error), but it's entirely subjective.

Comment: @David: The third option is also the one which gives most information if the assertion is false, but at the cost of more statements in the code.

Comment: I don't see that as a "cost" though.  Where is it written that code should be on as few lines as possible?  Readability and supportability is an asset, not a cost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally prefer the third one, and not just for readability, but for future mainainability and debugging. Imagine that one of the assertions suddenly starts failing some time after the code has been written. With either of the first two, you don't know exactly which condition is false, when one of those assertions fails.

But with the third one, there is absolutely no ambiguity.

Comment: Your answer makes sense, but still my example presents a special case. If a parameter is supposed to be outside of a certain range, say, then we will not be able to break the condition up into simpler expressions, for example `assert((m < 0) || (m > 10))`.

Comment: That's a valid case for putting more than one condition in an assertion. But like you said, it's not possible to break that condition up, so I don't know why this poses a question at all.

Comment: It poses a question because then you may find it more regular to also use e.g. `assert((n >= 0) && (n <= nmax))` rather than sometimes breaking a condition up and sometimes not.